# Is it possible to destroy "sortable" when "sortstart" starts?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, destroy

Here is my code:

```
$(".myclass").bind( "sortstart", function(event, ui) 
{ 
   $('#div_1').sortable('destroy');
   $("#div_1 .li_1").droppable(
   {
      hoverClass: 'red',
      drop: function(event, ui)
      {
         $(this).addClass('red');           
      }
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me identify what is wrong?

Comment: Does it even make any *sense* to **destroy** the Sortable when you **start sorting**? What are you trying to achieve!?

Comment: Hi MvanGeest, i have 3 DIVs. All 3 DIVs are sortable. But when i drag something from #div_2 or #div_3 into #div_1, all li in #div_1 must be sortable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. Could you build a small working example using jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: sure ;) ... http://jsfiddle.net/FrbW8/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it :)

```
$(".myclass").bind('mousedown',function()
{ 
   $('#div_1').sortable('destroy'); 
    });

$(".myclass").bind( "sortstart", function(event, ui) 
{
   $("#div_1 .li_1").droppable(
   {
      hoverClass: 'red',
      drop: function(event, ui)
      {
         $(this).addClass('red');           
      }
    });
});
```